# Python multiprocessing going on forever in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have been using the python multiprocessing package to achieve multiprocessing for a for-loop. There are multiple CSV Files and I am doing some operations on them . Finally, after processing, I am adding each CSV file to a pandas dataframe after processing. Following code might give you an idea.

I am reading filenames from a directory. The filenames are the file names of multiple CSV Files. Then these filenames are sent to the "task" function, and after processing, those CSV files are attached to the dataframe "df".

```
df = pd.DataFrame()


def task(filename):
    global df
    <stage df = some processing on filename.csv>
    df = pd.concat([stocks_data,stage])
```

After that, I am using multiprocessing function to achieve all this in a parrallel way because those CSV files can be processed individually and can be added separately to the main "df" dataframe.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(4)                         
names = os.listdir("file directory")
pool.map(task2, names)
```

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong? Both of these processes are running in different jupyter notebook cells, but the second cell keeps on running forever. I also added a print line in the task function to see if any progress is being made, but that print line is not being executed at all. Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: You should get rid of `df` and `global` and instead `return stage_df` in your `task` function. You can then collect them all using: `frames = pool.map(task, ...)` - Your pool code should also be inside an `if __name__ == '__main__'`.